# Issue with DataRow state in DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, rowstate

I have a very strange requirement using DataTable. I have a datatable with some columns. Nwo whenever there is any change in any of the DataRow in the datatable; then the state of DataRow is set to modified. That is OK. But for one exceptional column I don't want this behavior. I want that any change in any row for this particular column should not change the state of datarow. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert here however I don't think you can forbid the event to be triggered.

However you can change the way you handle this event.
Something like "if the modified cell is on the column XXX then leave; else continue the event handling".

hope it helps,